# How to run Windows 8 dev preview on native hardware without burning?

Tags: virtualization, windows-8-preview, rescue-disk

[This blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knom/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline) explains how to use the `diskpart` utility on the Windows 7 install DVD/USB to create a virtual drive you can mount and install Windows onto.

> At next startup, you’ll see Windows 7 in the boot menu!

Is this still possible with the Windows 8 dev preview DVD? Can I do this without burning the image to a DVD using virtualization? How do I extract the virtual disk image with Windows 8 from the virtual disk image used to virtualize? If I need to hand edit my bootloader how can I do that?

Comment: Scott Hanselman explains how to move the stuff from DVD to a USB flash drive http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Comment: Virtual box can make the vhd image from the W8 ISO

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Refer to the following blog post.

[Install Win 8 using VHD](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx)